# How to renew Kerberos ticket for Kafka in Spring?

Tags: hadoop, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kerberos, amqp

I have a Java Spring application (running on a server outside of Hadoop cluster) that connects to Kerberized Kafka topic (Secured by Kerberos on the Hadoop cluster) using KEYTAB file and pushes streaming data.

The issue I'm facing now is that the TGT gets regenerated every 24 hours and my Java application lose connection with Kafka.

This is the error log:

```
2018-05-12 10:57:01 WARN  NetworkClient:241 - [Producer clientId=amqp7] Connection to node 1001 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2018-05-12 10:57:01 WARN  Selector:246 - [Producer clientId=amqp7] Unexpected error from domain.com/1.2.3.4; closing connection
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This ticket is no longer valid
               at javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosTicket.toString(KerberosTicket.java:638)
               at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
               at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
               at sun.security.jgss.krb5.SubjectComber.findAux(SubjectComber.java:171)
               at sun.security.jgss.krb5.SubjectComber.find(SubjectComber.java:61)
               at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util.getTicket(Krb5Util.java:153)
               at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential$1.run(Krb5InitCredential.java:335)
               at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential$1.run(Krb5InitCredential.java:331)
               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
               at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getTgt(Krb5InitCredential.java:330)
               at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:145)
               at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
               at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
               at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
               at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
               at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
               at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
               at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$2.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:361)
               at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$2.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:359)
               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
               at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
               at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:359)
               at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.sendSaslClientToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:269)
               at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:206)
               at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:81)
               at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:474)
               at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:412)
               at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
               at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
               at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I kill the application and run it again it will successfully authenticate and push data into Kerberized Kafka without any error.

I have tried callback handler in Producer.send() method but there was no luck.

Any idea on how I can re-authenticate my client in the code on kerberos ticket renewal?

Comment: How is that keytab file used, actually? And by which library -- the Kafka client (principal/keytab mentioned in the JAAS config file under "Kafka Client" entry)? the Spring wrapper? some custom code? or an external call to `kinit`?